# AES Decryption is not giving correct values

Tags: .net-core, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using AES to encrypt a string and then decrypt the encrypted string to retrieve the original string. What I noticed is after decryption, some of the characters are missing from the original one. I have compiled the issue in a console app for your convenience. After decryption the string that I am getting is "5&&64&&41&&false"

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        var toEncryptReturn = program.EncryptString("5&&64&&41&&false&&&&dc&&", "mysmallkey123456");
        var toDecryptReturn = program.DecryptString(toEncryptReturn, "mysmallkey123456");
    }

    public string EncryptString(string text, string keyString)
    {
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

        using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, aesAlg.IV))
            {
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(text);
                    }

                    var iv = aesAlg.IV;

                    var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                    var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);
                    
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public string DecryptString(string cipherText, string keyString)
    {
        var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        var iv = new byte[16];
        var cipher = new byte[16];

        Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

        using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
            {
                string result;
                using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
                {
                    using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in separating IV and ciphertext in `DecryptSring()`. The length of the ciphertext is not properly taken into account, so the last part gets lost. The problem can be fixed as follows:

```cs
...
var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - iv.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length);
...
```

---

Note that for CBC a padding is mandatorily required if the length of the plaintext is not an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes for AES), as is the case here (for a 24 bytes plaintext).

Disabling the padding during encryption would immediately lead to a corresponding exception. The reason this does *not* happen in the posted code is that disabling padding is instructed *after* the `CreateEncryptor()` call, so it has no effect and the default PKCS#7 padding is not disabled.

However, when decrypting, disabling padding (or unpadding) is instructed *before* the `CreateDecryptor()` call, so it takes effect and the default PKCS#7 padding is disabled, i.e. the padding bytes added during encryption are not removed during decryption (which is easiest to check with a hex encoding of the decrypted data).

Therefore, the line `aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None` can (and should) be removed in *both* methods.